# Django - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: django

So every time I try to view someone's profile when they haven't entered a birth day I get this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'`. I followed this post to add the birthday/age to the user profile so no reason to include my code since I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39761072/12229283.

I tried adding a `default` to the model but that doesn't seem to work how do I make it so if a user doesn't enter a birthday just skip it and ignore it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an if / else to the return statement in your age method.

If there is no value for date_of_birth (i.e. it is set to None), you will get that error as you are calling dob.year, where dob = date_of_birth = None.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

    def age(self):
        import datetime
        if self.date_of_birth:
            dob = self.date_of_birth
            tod = datetime.date.today()
            my_age = (tod.year - dob.year) - int((tod.month, tod.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
            return my_age
        else:
            return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in the admin>LogEntry after Django upgrade to 3.2.4. The issue was in using `date_hierarchy`.